# Drawing tiled bitmap with bottom alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, bitmap, android-bitmap

I want to draw an image with gradient background. I've created a drawable bitmap resource like below

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/bg"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        />
```

As you know, gravity is ignored when tileMode is defined. I tried creating my own class which is inherited from BitmapDrawable, but I couldn't achieve success with that. 
Please help me to apply both properties: tileMode and gravity.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question clearly. What is the goal here?

Is it using a gradient image (like .png .jpg) with tileMode?

Or is it using a transparent icon and making it's background gradient?

Also why would you need gravity when you are using tileMode? tileMode means tile the whole area of bitmap with the same image. Since it will do it to the whole image no point giving gravity on that image since all of it will be filled.

If the goal is to use this drawable bitmap in the some part of the screen add this to your layout:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/mydrawablebitmap"
android:id="@+id/imageview1" />
```

You can put it to your layout.xml and set your own width and height and align whichever you like.

If the goal is using an image and making its background here is how you go with it:

Create a gradient.xml in your drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
    android:startColor="#E0E0E0"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:angle="-90"/>
</shape>
```

Then add this imageview to your layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimagewithgradientbackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:src="@drawable/foregroundimage" />
```

If you give me some more details about the question I'll go ahead and edit my answer accordingly.